# Can't add a point in highchart live data reading from a mysql database

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ajax, highcharts

I modified the highcharts live data code, so U could read values from a mysql database.

But when the program has to draw the graph, using the values read from the db, no points are added.

The values are received as an array, in json format, through the `requestdata` function.

I think the problem in this part of the code:

```
chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);
```

because, if instead of using point, I add manually values, like 4 and 5, the points are showed correctly in the graph.

Here is my index.php code: (full program)

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Luis

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/themes/gray.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
        <!-- 2. Add the JavaScript to initialize the live chart on document ready -->
    <script>
    var chart; // global

    /**
     * Request data from the server, add it to the graph and set a timeout to request again
     */
    function requestData() {             // Defino la funcion requestData, la misma no se ejecuta en esta instancia
      $.ajax({                   // Llamo a la funcion ajax
        url: 'data.php',     
        dataType: "json",
          // Direccion a donde envio la peticion
        success: function(point) {       
          // Si la peticion es exitosa, recibo la data desde el servidor
          var series = chart.series[0],    // Se guarda la informacion de la serie en la variable series
            shift = series.data.length > 40; // Desplazo hacia la derecha cuando se se imprimen mas de 20 puntos. El grafico me permite visualizar hasta 20 puntos.

          // Grafico la serie en pantalla (en este caso particular, 1 solo punto)
          chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);

          // Luego de 1 segundo, se llama nuevamente a la funcion que desde el servidor nos trae un punto diferente para graficar. Esto es recursivo, se repite indefinidamente
          setTimeout(requestData, 1000);  
        },
        cache: false
      });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {          // Es la primera funcion que se ejecuta (porque incluye el "ready"), establece las caracteristicas del grafico
      chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
         renderTo: 'live_graph',   // Indica donde renderiza el grafico (ver en el body)

          defaultSeriesType: 'spline',    // Tipo de Grafico

          events: {
            load: requestData       // Cuando finaliza de cargar el grafico, llama a la funcion "requestData"
          }
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Temperatura del Horno'      // Titulo del Grafico
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {
          minPadding: 0.2, 
          maxPadding: 0.2,
          title: {
            text: 'Temperaturas',
            margin: 80
          }

        },


        series: [{
          name: 'Temperatura',        // Nombre de la serie de datos
          data: []              // Los datos de la serie. Al estar vacio, es porque los mismos vienen de otro lado
        }]
      });   
    });
    </script>
<br>
<br>
    <!-- Espacio reservado para el Grafico -->

    <div id="live_graph" style="width: 1100px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How your json from data.php looks like?